# Row-wise Boolean comparison of data

Tags: r

I have grouped my data by the appropriate grouping, and I need to be sure that "x" and "y" values equal each other for each unique combination of Group1 and Group2. In other words, what code could I use to cycle through this dataset and ensure that A1x == A1y and A2x == A2y, etc.

```
"Group1","Group2","group3","values"
"A"        "1"       x       10
"A"        "1"       y       10
"A"        "2"       x       15 
"A"        "2"       y       15
```

To help make the answer easier, here is the data.frame from the example

```
    d <- data.frame(Group1= c("A", "A", "A", "A"), 
                    Group2= c("1", "1", "2", "2"), 
                    group3= c("x", "y", "x", "y"), 
                    values= c(10, 10, 15, 15))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dplyr`, you can do:

```
d %>%
 group_by(Group1, Group2) %>%
 mutate(cond = all(values == first(values)))

  Group1 Group2 group3 values cond 
  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>   <dbl> <lgl>
1 A      1      x          10 TRUE 
2 A      1      y          10 TRUE 
3 A      2      x          15 TRUE 
4 A      2      y          15 TRUE
```

Or:

```
d %>%
 group_by(Group1, Group2) %>%
 mutate(cond = n_distinct(values) == 1)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! also, these answers would both work, no matter how many groups there were, wouldn't they? The first answer makes sure that all of the values equal the first value, whereas the second answer just check that there is only one distinct value.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this with `pivot_wider`:

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(d, names_from='group3', values_from='values') %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(eq=x==y)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you went too far into turning your data into a long format maybe this is easier to manipulate

```
d %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = group3,values_from = values) %>% 
  mutate(is_equal = x == y)
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. To be fair, I prefer to work with longer data. Also, the dataset came longer. Thanks for the input, though!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `ave()` to make it

```
d <- within(d,isequal <- as.logical(ave(values,Group1,Group2,FUN = function(v) v==unique(v))))
```

such that

```
> d
  Group1 Group2 group3 values isequal
1      A      1      x     10    TRUE
2      A      1      y     10    TRUE
3      A      2      x     15    TRUE
4      A      2      y     15    TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option if the data is grouped properly and has 2 rows for each group:

```
d$check <- rep(d$values[seq(1L,nrow(d),2L)]==d$values[seq(2L,nrow(d),2L)], each=2L)
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple way would be to merge the sub tables with group x and group y to compare the values.

```
> d[d$group3=="y",]

#      Group1 Group2 group3 values
#    2      A      1      y     10
#    4      A      2      y     15

> merge(d[d$group3=="y",],d[d$group3=="x",],by=c("Group1","Group2"))

#  Group1 Group2 group3.x values.x group3.y values.y
#  1      A      1        y       10        x       10
#  2      A      2        y       15        x       15


 with(merge(d[d$group3=="y",], d[d$group3=="x",],
      by=c("Group1","Group2")),
      values.x==values.y)

 ## [1] TRUE TRUE
```

Of course you have fancier ways of doing it but it is not bad to start simple first